# Error handling node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to learn node.js

I've got a working function and trying to handle an exeption like this:

```
Client.Session.create(device, storage, username, password)
    .then(function(session) {
        session.getAccount()
          .then(function(account) {
           console.log(account.params)
           res.statusCode = 200
           res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
           res.end(JSON.stringify(account.params));  
           return session   
    })
    }).catch(Exceptions.AuthenticationError, function(err) {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

but it isn't working I'm still getting this in case of invalid login:

> Unhandled rejection AuthenticationError: The username you entered doesn't appear to belong to an account. Please check your username and try again.

Comment: There is a long running closed issue about this problem : https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/830  it seems to be related to the async behaviour of the authentication exception.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code or errors as others can't search for the same using Google or SO's own search. It also affects users using scree readers. Also, in this case the text in the screenshot is barely legible.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Client.Session.create(device, storage, username, password)
    .then(function(session) {
        return session.getAccount() <-- NOTICE THE RETURN STATEMENT!!
          .then(function(account) {
           console.log(account.params)
           res.statusCode = 200
           res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
           res.end(JSON.stringify(account.params));
           return session
        })
    }).catch(Exceptions.AuthenticationError, function(err) {
            console.log(err)
    })
```

Without the return, the .then handler of the promise returned by Client.Session.Create(...) will return a resolved promise (this is its default behaviour).

Promise rejections aren't any kind of exceiptions, so they aren't automatically rethrown as it would be if you were added, for example, something like this:

```
session.getAccount(...).then(...).catch(function(){throw "FooBar"});
```

Comment: Also worth noting: make sure you're dealing with bluebird promises because `.catch(Exceptions.AuthenticationError, function(err) {...})` is a [filtered catch](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html#filtered-catch) extension specific to only (afaik) bluebird implementation.